# Executing a function for all instances of a class?AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, flash-cs6

I'm really new to AS3 and I was wondering how I can apply a function to all instances of a class I'll show you guys what I have, is there anything I can do?

```
var cloud:Cloud;
for (i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    cloud = new Cloud();
    addChild(cloud);
}
```

this makes many instances of the Cloud class.
Later on I want to execute a function on all of these instances at once, how would I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store them in an [`Array`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html) or [`Vector`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Vector.html):

```
var clouds:Vector.<Cloud> = new <Cloud>[];

for(var i:int = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    var cloud:Cloud = new Cloud();

    clouds.push(cloud);
    addChild(cloud);
}
```

Then [iterate over that list](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/statements.html#for_each..in) and call a function on each item:

```
for each(var cloud:Cloud in clouds)
{
    cloud.do();
}
```

Comment: @Altrows You can manipulate all the clouds in whatever manner you like using the same loop e.g. `somewhereElse.addChild(cloud)`.

Comment: Yea I figured that out about 10 seconds before you replied, thanks anyway :)